# Django - How to filter a Many-to-Many-to-Many relantionship

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have 3 models (`User` is Django's built in user-model):

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Listing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Listing Name', max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="listings", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField('Active', default=True)
    
class Bid(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, related_name="listing_bids", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bidder =  models.ForeignKey(User,  related_name="user_bids", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('listing', 'bidder',)
```

Basically a `Listing` can have multiple `Bids` from different `Users`

Now I would like to get the `Listing` row and it's corresponding  `Bid` row where `Listing = x` and `User = y`

I am **able** to get a queryset returned when I do this:

```
Listing.objects.get(pk=8).listing_bids.all()
```

**But** now I'd like to filter that queryset further based on the `bidder` where `user=xx` (or `username = xx`).

I should then only get one row back (that is if the `Listing` and `User` exist on the `Bid` table) or `None`should be returned.

It seems so simple to do but I can't figure it out -  besides "looping" through all the rows myself.

Comment: `Listing.objects.get(pk=8).listing_bids.filter(bidder__username='xx')
`

Comment: Thanks @Sergio2405 - that works. As a side question: would I be able to do this in a template / html file?

Comment: Yeah, you can use filter inside the template. I recommend you to also check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/ to see more examples about filters with ForeignKey fields

Comment: Thanks @Sergio2405, I have checked the documentation but the sometimes don't list these "side-cases". As for the Template: This works: `{{ listing.listing_bids.all }}`  but this does not: `{{ listing.listing_bids.all.bidder }}`. I was hoping to do something like this in the template: `{% if user in listing.listing_bids.all.bidder %}`

Comment: That won' work because when you call all() gives you a list of elements `listing.listing_bids.all[0].bidder` will work. Iterate through the elements

Comment: I tried this in my template `{{ listing.listing_bids.all[0] }}`  but got an error: `TemplateSyntaxError Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'listing.listing_bids.all[0]'`

Comment: Oh sorry, you needed to add () because all is a method like `all()[0]` to get the first element of the list

Comment: Thanks @Sergio2405 I am still getting errors - can you actually index lists in the template / html?